# How can I transform my data frame into this specific format in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

My current data frame in `R` has only 2 columns, namely longitude and latitude. There are around 1500 records (rows) and they include lots of duplicates.

An extract of the data frame is shown below:

```
longitude   latitude
57.408999   -20.208104
57.667991   -20.13641
57.539122   -20.103416
57.502332   -20.124798
57.414653   -20.261872
57.65949    -20.126768
57.468383   -20.223031
57.754464   -20.25823
57.754464   -20.25823
57.680745   -20.121893
57.65949    -20.179457
57.669408   -20.177538
57.702715   -20.211515
```

I want to convert this data frame into the following format:

```
longitude   latitude    emp emp2
57.408999   -20.208104  1   0.1
57.667991   -20.13641   11  1.1
57.539122   -20.103416  16  1.6
57.502332   -20.124798  10  1
57.414653   -20.261872  1   0.1
57.65949    -20.126768  2   0.2
57.468383   -20.223031  17  1.7
57.754464   -20.25823   9   0.9
57.754464   -20.25823   13  1.3
57.680745   -20.121893  13  1.3
57.65949    -20.179457  4   0.4
57.669408   -20.177538  3   0.3
57.702715   -20.211515  1   0.1
```

`emp` will be a new column which is the frequency of each longitude and latitude. Thus my data frame will now only have unique longitude and latitude with their respective counts.

`emp2` is simply the value of `emp` divided by 10

Can this be done with R? If yes, any help would be highly appreciated.

Since I am new to R, I am confused as to where to start to solve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way with `dplyr` would be

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(longitude, latitude) %>%
  summarise(emp = n(), 
            emp2 = emp/10)
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative `base R` solution using `aggregate`.

```
attach(df)
df <- aggregate(df, by=list(longitude, latitude), FUN=length)
colnames(df) <- c('longitude', 'latitude', 'emp', 'emp2')
df$emp2 <- df$emp2 / 10
```